# How to send multiple characteristics under one BLE Service stm32wb15

Tags: embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, accelerometer, sensors

I try to read 2 characteristics ( accelerometer and distance laser sensor )under one BLE Service. I can read distance data successfully but other AccelValueZ data is always zero.SensorHeightValue is int16_t type. How to read this two data from my phone ? Code is :

````
void MPU6050_Receive_Sensor_Data(void){
    double xAccel ,yAccel ,zAccel;
    mpu6050_get_measurement(&xAccel, &yAccel, &zAccel);
    P2P_Server_App_Context.SensorControl.MPU6050AccelValueX = xAccel;
    P2P_Server_App_Context.SensorControl.MPU6050AccelValueY = yAccel;
    P2P_Server_App_Context.SensorControl.MPU6050AccelValueZ = zAccel;
    P2PS_STM_App_Update_Char(P2P_READ1_CHAR_UUID, (uint8_t *)&P2P_Server_App_Context.SensorControl.MPU6050AccelValueZ);

    if((P2P_Server_App_Context.SensorControl.MPU6050AccelValueZ <= 100) && (P2P_Server_App_Context.SensorControl.MPU6050AccelValueZ >= -100)){
        VL53L1X_Receive_Sensor_Data_Action();
    }

    return;

}

void VL53L1X_Receive_Sensor_Data(void){
    P2P_Server_App_Context.SensorControl.SensorHeightValue = vl53l1x_get_measurement();
    P2PS_STM_App_Update_Char(P2P_READ_CHAR_UUID, (uint8_t *)&P2P_Server_App_Context.SensorControl.SensorHeightValue);
//  P2PS_STM_App_Update_Char(P2P_READ1_CHAR_UUID, (uint8_t *)&P2P_Server_App_Context.SensorControl.MPU6050AccelValueZ);

    return;
}```
````